# Firebase Notification Inbox in Web App (Not FCM)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification

I'm trying to implement notification inbox similar to stack overflow inbox where I can see related notification.

[image]

For now, I just want user to be notified whenever new comment is posted in the post (show number of notification when user logs in and whenever user opens that inbox it should go away).

I'm not sure how this can be done using firebase and how I should structure the data.

I'm thinking of having a comment collection inside a Post collection and use the onSnapshot to listen to changes in Post collection but how would i actually implement the notification part (whether comment is read or not)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to have a `collection` just for notifications like `notifications/{userUid}/notifications/{notificationID}` like here:

[image]

We use that structure for all of our apps that have such a feature. The notification itself is send using FCM but we store the data of it in such a separate `collection`. It also has the value `isRead` where we store just a boolean or a timestamp when the notification is read from the user. Each user has his own notifications collection and can only see those and change only the `isRead` value by the security rules.

With a limit query we show him only the last 25 to 50 messages.

If you don't know how to trigger the sending of the notifications: You will need to use the Firebase Cloud Functions and setup a trigger when a post/comment is created and send an FCM message and a notification in your users notifications collection as shown above.

Comment: Is there any other way of implementing this without using FCM?

Comment: You need FCM to send the push notification. If you don't need them and just need the notification inbox just do everything without FCM. There are third party solutions for Push Notifications but I don't see any reason to use them. You already use Firebase and FCM for free.

Comment: Hello Tarik, Thanks for your response.

Comment: I don't want to add a push notifications functionality. I simply want to show notifications as a list when someone presses a notification bell.