# How to show notifications using Firebase Firestore in React App

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I plan to build a notification system using ReactJs and Firebase, so when users comment on a particular solution on my website, the person who submitted the solution can see notifications by clicking on the notification bell with the person's name who commented on the solution, similar to a platform like hashnode.

I have a separate subcollection called `comments` under the `solutions` collections for each solution document, and each comment is itself a document under the subcollection `comments`.

I would like to know what approach I should use to add a notification system using Firestore to my react website?

One solution that I can think of is **I'll create one collection on firestore and will name it `notifications`, and I'll add an onSnapshot listener on this `notifications` collection so that when a user adds a new comment, It'll call the addDocument function to add a new `notification document` to the `notifications` collection and then I'll render a list of notification from a notifications collection when someone click on the notification bell icon.**

Comment: Try reading this post and see if it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68919393/firebase-notification-inbox-in-web-app-not-fcm

Comment: Hey Min, thanks for sharing this. But I only want to achieve this functionality using cloud firestore?

Comment: you dont have to use cloud function. You can just add new notification doc whenever user comments. What you proposed is a completely viable option.

Comment: okay, so I'll go with that. Thanks